# jQuery and IE 8 and a toggler only opens first child

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, slidetoggle

I have a group of divs like such where I could have x number like the divs below on the page.

Here is the div code

```
<div class="demo1">
    <h3 class="expand2">1:00 pm – 4:00pm<br>Item 1<p></p>
<p><strong>Presented by:</strong><em><br></em></p></h3>
<div class="collapse" style="display: none; ">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center">
<tbody><tr>
<td align="left" valign="top">
<div id="speakerBlockArea">
<div id="leftcolumnSpeakerBlock"><span id="sessTitle">run by:</span></div>
<div id="rightcolumnSpeakerBlock">
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".collapse").slideUp();  
    $("H3.expand2").click(function() {  
    //$(this).next(".collapse:first").slideToggle("slow");
        $(".collapse").toggle($('.collapse').css('display') == 'none');  
    });  
});
```

I finally got everything working with IE 8 and the rest of the browsers but now I have a problem where every div expands when I click on just one of them.  How can I get it to work so that only the child expands when parent is clicked.  And so that it works in IE 8/9

The test link with the code as it stands now is 
http://www.lvtravelshow.com/?page_id=2028

I have already a version of code that works in Chrome / Firefox etc.  But IE is having the issue so I ended up with the above code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not cleaned up yet but it works.
It won't let me post the code here so maybe later

Comment: Did you solve this? Please answer your own question and mark it as correct so that it is not shown in the unanswered list :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean sth like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".collapse").slideUp();  
    $("H3.expand2").click(function() {  
        $(this).parent('div').find('.collapse').toggle();  
    });  
});​
```

$(this).parent('div').find('.collapse').toggle(); <---
this line is to find out the .collapse div of the clicked parent, and toggle it